# CMake link against a specific library version

Tags: c, cmake, shared-libraries

Let's say I have a library called `libfoo.so.0.1.0` and I want to link against this in CMake.

The library sits in the `libs` directory

My CMake looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(using_shared_library)

add_executable(main main.c)

target_link_directories(main
    PUBLIC libs)
    
target_link_libraries(main libfoo.so.0.1.0)
```

The link line generated from this includes:

```
 -Llibs -lfoo
```

I'd like CMake to generate:

```
-Llibs -l:libfoo.so.0.1.0
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Just use **absolute** path to the library: `target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/libfoo.so.0.1.0)`.

Answer (score 2):

This depends a lot on `libfoo`...

Does it provide a CMake package? Then

```
find_package(foo 0.1.0 REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(myTarget PRIVATE foo::foo)
```

is most appropriate.

If it has pkg-config, then you can use:

```
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(foo REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET foo=0.1.0)

target_link_libraries(myTarget PRIVATE PkgConfig::foo)
```

But if it's really just checked in to version control, then you can use an absolute path:

```
target_link_libraries(myTarget PRIVATE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/libfoo.so.0.1.0")
```